# BroadcastReceiver not catching the INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, referrer

i created an app that has a BroadcastReceiver that catches a `INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast.

When I'm installing the app with eclipse and creating a broadcast with adb I see that all work fine, the LogCat is displaying all that it should be.
But when I'm installing the app from the play store nothing is showing on the logcat.
If I understand correctly, the play store app should create a broadcast witch the app that is being installed supposed to catch, right?

Thats basicly what im doing:

```
public class SDK_Referrer extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"))
        {
            String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
            if (!(referrer == null || referrer.length() == 0))
            {
                // extracting the relevant data to Map
                Log.d("SAMPLE", "Generating Ymid from referrel");
                Map<String, String> referralmap = 
                    createHashMapFromQueryString(referrer);
                Log.d("SAMPLE", "Ymid is: " + referralmap.get("ymid"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i only want to send someting to a server when the app is being installed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the receiver to your manifest, so your app knows you have something listening for the broadcast. Something like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.cool.SDK_Referrer" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```